# ScheduledExecutorService для длительного времени: schedule VS scheduleAtFixedRate

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-threads

Как лучше организовать заведомо долгий отложенный поток?

Насколько сильно мучается телефон выполняя каждый из этих потоков?

А если для случая #2 секунды сменить на милисекунды? Наносекунды?

p.s. это выполняется в `ForegroundService`

## 1. Отложить выполнение кода на 24 часа

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.schedule(new Runnable() {
// JOB
}, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

***ИЛИ***

## 2. Каждую секунду сравнивать текущее VS целевое время (изначально между ними разница в 24 часа)

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

if (текущее время >= выбранного времени){
    //JOB
}   
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 4):

Для вашей цели следует использовать инструменты, которые предоставляет Android для запуска отложенных задач, например [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager), [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) или библиотеку [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager). Дело в том, что `ForegroundService` вообще не даст телефону уснуть в течении всего этого времени, что вызовет заметный расход батареи вашим приложением на фоне других. `ScheduledExecutorService` это чисто класс Java и больше предназначен для бекенд приложений, которые выполняются постоянно. Android приложения не должны выполняться постоянно если нет для этого необходимости (а ее нет, если нужно просто ждать). Поэтому лучше предоставить запуск запланированной задачи Android.

Comment: спасибо за совет! обязательно им воспользуюсь. НО! хотелось бы услышать ответ на мой вопрос относительной `schedule VS scheduleatfixedrat`. что больше требует затрат на ресурсы? пусть и не в таком большом промежутке и не для фонового процесса.

Comment: а `AlarmManager` сработает, если закрыть активити приложения?

Comment: К сожалению не могу ответить на этот вопрос, но предполагаю, что разницы между ними особой нет, т.к. процесс все равно выполняется, не важно запускает он Runnable каждую секунду или только через 24 часа.

Comment: AlarmManager работает при закрытом приложении (как при выходе с помощью кнопки назад пока все активити не закроются, так и при выгрузке его из меню запущенных смахиванием). Но если пользователь закрыл приложение принудительно из настроек устройства, то AlarmManager не будет работать и запустится только после того как пользователь откроет приложение снова вручную.

Comment: а система не пытается убить `AlarmManager`, как `ForegroundService` ?

Comment: Нет, система будет стараться выполнить установленный Alarm как можно точнее к заданному времени. ForegroundService также не убивается, этот вид службы система наоборот будет максимально стараться оставить в живых и может убить только при сильной нехватке памяти.  Вышесказанное применимо к большинству Android устройств, но не относится к некоторым китайским прошивкам, которые могут по своему желанию останавливать все службы и будильники приложения для сохранения батареи пока приложение не будет добавлено в белый список.